# How is the state $|a_0 a_i\rangle$ physical?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, brst

For a state $|\psi\rangle$ to be physical we require that:

$$\langle\psi|a_0^\dagger a_0|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|a_i^\dagger a_i|\psi\rangle$$

It is always said that physical state must contain equal numbers of longitudial and temporal photons so let us try $|\psi\rangle = a^\dagger_0 a^\dagger_i |0\rangle$ as a state that is to be physical. (is it ? Why wouldn't it be ?)

The left hand side becomes:

$$\langle 0| a_0 a_i a^\dagger_0 a_0 a^\dagger_0 a^\dagger_i | 0\rangle = \langle 0|a_i a^\dagger_ia_0  a^\dagger_0 a_0 a^\dagger_0  | 0\rangle$$

$$\langle 0|(1+a^\dagger_ia_i)(-1+a^\dagger_0a_0)(-1+a^\dagger_0a_0)|\rangle$$

$$\langle 0|(1)(-1+a^\dagger_0a_0)(-1)|\rangle = \langle 0|(1)(-1)(-1)|\rangle = 1$$

The right hand side becomes:

$$\langle 0| a_0 a_i a^\dagger_i a_i a^\dagger_0 a^\dagger_i | 0\rangle = \langle 0|a_0 a^\dagger_0 a_i  a^\dagger_i a_i a^\dagger_i  | 0\rangle$$

$$\langle 0|(-1+a^\dagger_0 a_0)(1+a^\dagger_ia_i)(1+a^\dagger_ia_i)|\rangle$$

$$\langle 0|(-1)(1+a^\dagger_ia_i)(1)|\rangle = \langle 0|(-1)(1)(1)|\rangle = -1$$

Such that $rhs \neq lhs$ and the state appears to by unphysical.

**The question**
One of the following statements must be true but I can't figure out which one and why. I'm sorry in advance if this is trivial (it should be) but I'm really confused at the moment:

1. the state that I tested is indeed unphysical, but why would that be? It contains an equal number of longitudinal and temporal photons so it it should be physical.
2. I have made a sign or conceptual error in my calculation that I fail to spot.

Comment: For any vector $\psi$, the quantity $(\psi,b^*b\psi)$ is non-negative, since it $= \Vert b\psi\Vert^2$ . I then wonder how the RHS can be negative...

Comment: $a_0$ is a timelike annihilator such that $[a_0,a_0^\dagger]=-1$ that is what causes the minus signs

Comment: How does that make a vector norm negative?

Comment: if your vector is $a^\dagger_0|0\rangle = 0$ with $|0\rangle$ defined as the state for which $a|0\rangle=0$ and $[a,a^\dagger]=-1$ you find that the norm of that vector is 0.
Its well known in quantum field theory and the whole point of the Gupta Bleuler constraint is that these negative norm state should not contribute to the endresult. My question is that I can't figure out why not I must have made some stupid error I think.

Comment: The canonical norm on a Hilbert space is obviously non-negative and non-degenerate, so that a vector with zero norm is the zero vector. Are you mixing it with the Minkowski (pseudo-)norm?

Comment: yes it is indeed a pseudo-norm sorry for not pointing that out. However, this still doesn't explain why the Gupta-Bleuler condition fails to be satisfied :/

Comment: @Phoenix87 it is a feature of covariant quantization. We start with an inner product space where states don't necessarily have positive norm. Then we apply the constraints and prove that the remaining space has positive norm and thus in theory is habitable for a quantum mechanical theory.

Comment: Again, both the lhs and the rhs in the OP are non-negative as written

Comment: What is wrong than ?
You are not really helpful by stating that I am wrong without pinpointing my mistake... 
And as @SolenodonParadoxus pointed out my calculation is correct I was not interpretting it correctly

Comment: @Phoenix87 I am saying that $\left< 0 \right| a_0 a_0^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> = -1$. Do you imply that it is wrong?

Comment: @ gertian I think it is more helpful to point out that there is a mistake somewhere so that you can have another go at it, rather than fix it for you. @SolenodonParadoxus An operator of the form $aa^*$ (or $a^*a$) is positive. Therefore no diagonal element can be negative as I have pointed out in my first comment. This is because $(a\psi,a\psi)=(\psi,a^*a\psi)=\Vert a\psi\Vert^2\geq 0$.

Comment: @Phoenix87 you are ignorant and incorrect. Again, you can't use the $||\psi||^2 > 0$ axiom here. We are dealing with an inner product space for which it is not true.

Comment: Whatever mate...

Comment: @Phoenix87 didn't mean to offend you. You're just wrong, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused by the first statement in your question.

Normally, in the Gupta-Bleuler method we require physical states to satisfy

$$ (a_0 - a_3) \left| \Psi \right> = 0, $$

which is a quantized version of the Lorentz gauge constraint in the momentum space

$$ p_{\mu} A^{\mu} = 0, $$

provided that we choose the $x^3$ axis along the photon's momentum.

The space of solutions of this constraint decomposes into physical states generated by $a_{1,2}^{\dagger}$ and spurious states generated by $a_0^{\dagger} - a_3^{\dagger}$ which can be shown to have zero norm:

$$ \left< 0 \right| (a_0 - a_3) (a_0^{\dagger} - a_3^{\dagger}) \left| 0 \right> = 0. $$

These can be artificially excluded from the inner product space, after which we obtain the physical Hilbert space.

The states generated by $a_0^{\dagger} + a_3^{\dagger}$ don't satisfy the constraint and are thus unphysical.

Note that your state which is $a_0^{\dagger}a_3^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right>$ doesn't satisfy the constraint:

$$ (a_0 - a_3) a_0^{\dagger} a_3^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> \neq 0, $$

and thus it is unphysical. This is because we can't represent the operator $a_0^{\dagger} a_3^{\dagger}$ solely as a function of $a_1^{\dagger}$, $a_2^{\dagger}$ and $a_0^{\dagger} - a_3^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer all is clear now.
The great thing is, what got my confused in the first place appears to be correct so I don't have to throw away my work due to my confusion :)